# partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{k^4}{(a\, k^3-1)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, partial-fractions

I have to perform complex partial fraction decomposition of the following term:

$$\frac{k^4}{(a \, k^3-1)^2}$$

where $a$ is a real positive number.

and I would like to know if it is possible to reduce it to a sum of fractions of the type $\frac{A}{k\pm z}$,$\frac{B \, k}{k^2\pm z}$,$\frac{C \, k}{k^2-y}$ or similar. Where $z$ is a complex number and $y$ is a real number.

If it is not possible to reduce it to the kind of fraction I listed above other type of decomposition might work too.

Any hint on the process, or any reference would be nice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the fact that $\alpha^3-\beta^3=(\alpha-\beta)(\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2)$, where $\alpha=a^{1/3}k$ and $\beta=1$?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by making the change of variable $ak^{3} = x^{3}$, which transforms the expression into

$$ a^{3/4}\frac{x^{4}}{(x^{3} - 1)^{2}}.$$

Now we factorise the denominator. This is easy since we have a difference of two cubes.

$$ x^{3} - 1 = (x-1)(x^{2} + x + 1).$$

Notice that the quadratic is irreducible over the reals. Then (ignoring the constant $a^{3/4}$) we have

$$ \frac{x^{4}}{(x-1)^{2}(x^{2} + x + 1)} = \frac{A}{x - 1} + \frac{B}{(x-1)^{2}} + \frac{Cx + D}{x^{2} + x + 1} + \frac{Ex + F}{(x^{2} + x + 1)^{2}}.$$

Comment: Can't you further decompose the last two fractions considering the complex roots of the denominator?

Comment: @SSCNapoli Yes, but typically it's not done that way.

Comment: I can continue with the complex partial decomposition of that term myself. You said that the quadratic term is irreducible over the reals, but is it so also over the complex? I don't see any way to further reduce it...

Comment: @SSCNapoli The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra guarantees that every $n$-th order polynomial has $n$ complex roots, and can be written as a product of $n$ linear factors. In this case $x^2 + x +1 = (x + \frac{1}{2} - i\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}})(x + \frac{1}{2} + i\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}})$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $a=b^3$ and denominator will be factored as
$$\left(b^3 k^3-1\right)^2=(b k-1)^2 \left(b^2 k^2+b k+1\right)^2$$
Then you decompose in partial fractions
$$\frac{e+f k}{b^2 k^2+b k+1}+\frac{g+h k}{\left(b^2 k^2+b k+1\right)^2}+\frac{c}{b k-1}+\frac{d}{(b k-1)^2}$$
where $c,d,e,f,g,h$ are unknowns and must be obtained solving a six equations linear system. First you add all the fractions and consider the numerator of the result

$b^5 c k^5+b^4 c k^4+b^4 d k^4+b^4 e k^4+b^4 f k^5+b^3 c k^3+2 b^3 d k^3-b^3 e k^3-b^3 f k^4-b^2 c k^2+3 b^2 d k^2+b^2 g k^2+b^2 h k^3-b c k+2 b d k-b e k-b f k^2-2 b g k-2 b h k^2-c+d+e+f k+g+h k$

Numerator must be identical to $k^4$ so coefficients (from degree 0 up to 5 must be $\{0,0,0,0,1,0\}$

The system has quite nice solutions
$$c= \frac{2}{9 b^4},d= \frac{1}{9 b^4},e= \frac{4}{9 b^4},f= -\frac{2}{9 b^3},g= -\frac{1}{3 b^4},h= 0$$
Therefore the starting fraction can be written as
$$\frac{1}{9b^4}\left(-\frac{2 (b k-2)}{b^2 k^2+b k+1}-\frac{3}{\left(b^2 k^2+b k+1\right)^2}+\frac{2}{b k-1}+\frac{1}{(b k-1)^2}\right)$$

with $b={a}^\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: as I commented also to the other answer, can't you keep decomposing the fractions considering the complex roots of the denominators?

Answer (score 0):

Decompose MR.wolframalpha's solution, on $\omega^3=1$
$\dfrac{1}{3(2\omega+1)}\bigg(\dfrac1{x-\omega^2}-\dfrac 1{x-\omega}\bigg)+\dfrac1{x-1}+\dfrac {1}{3(x-1)^2}+1$